# How to get event when any new file added in Download folder in macOS programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want an event when new file get's added in download folder. My application trigger Safari/Chrome or any browser and it download the file from server. I want to watch/detect when file get downloaded in application.

Comment: You can use this tool : http://macappstore.org/fswatch/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmacos%5D+watch+folder

Comment: You can try setting up an observer for [NSDistributedNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdistributednotificationcenter?language=objc)'s `com.apple.DownloadFileFinished` notification.